# Docker compose - services.vulcain.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I'm using `Symfony` and `docker`, and believe I've made an error setting up those two, that made me ran into this error in docker compose :

`services.vulcain.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object`

while running a docker compose command :

`dc exec php vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --filter 'App\\Tests\\EntityTests::testName'`

I'll precise my folder architecture may be the issue:

I have a folder `/project` that is the route of the project

In which there is two folders `/frontend` and `/backend`, plus this script to launch back and front:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f backend/docker-compose.yml up -d ; 
docker-compose -f frontend/docker-compose.yml up -d ;
```

`/frontend` not being relevant for me, I launched my commands from `/api` fodler

Which himself contain `/docker` (with the dockerfile) and `/api` folder and my docker-compose.

My `docker-compose` comes from api-platform documentation:

```
version: '3.4'

x-cache-from:
  - &api-cache-from
    cache_from:
      - ${NGINX_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/nginx}
      - ${PHP_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/php}

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
      <<: *api-cache-from
    image: ${PHP_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/php}
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
    depends_on:
      - db
      - dev-tls
    volumes:
      - ./api:/srv/api:rw,cached
      - ./api/docker/php/conf.d/api-platform.dev.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/api-platform.ini
      - dev-certs:/certs:ro,nocopy
    networks:
      - symfony

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_nginx
      <<: *api-cache-from
    image: ${NGINX_IMAGE:-quay.io/api-platform/nginx}
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - ./api/public:/srv/api/public:ro
    networks:
      - symfony

  vulcain:
    image: dunglas/vulcain
    environment:
      - CERT_FILE=/certs/localhost.crt
      - KEY_FILE=/certs/localhost.key
      - UPSTREAM=http://api
    depends_on:
      - api
      - dev-tls
    volumes:
      - dev-certs:/certs:ro,nocopy
    ports:
      - ${VULC_TARGET}:${VULC_PUBLISHED}
    networks:
      - symfony

  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "${DB_TARGET}:${DB_PUBLISHED}"
    networks:
      - symfony

  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
      - CERT_FILE=/certs/localhost.crt
      - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
      - DEMO=1
      - JWT_KEY=${JWT_KEY}
      - KEY_FILE=/certs/localhost.key
      - PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://localhost:1337
    depends_on:
      - dev-tls
    volumes:
      - dev-certs:/certs:ro,nocopy
    ports:
      - "${MERC_TARGET}:${MERC_PUBLISHED}"
    networks:
      - symfony

  dev-tls:
    build:
      context: ./docker/dev-tls
    volumes:
      - dev-certs:/certs:rw
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
    networks:
      - symfony

volumes:
  db-data: {}
  dev-certs: {}

networks:
  symfony:
    driver: bridge
```

And the errors:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './../docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.mercure.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.vulcain.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

comes from the way I precise the ports in my docker-compose, given they came from the .env file located in the `/backend` folder and I'm executing my comand one folder lower in the `/api` folder.

But if I execute the same comand from `/backend`, I get this message :

```
Time: 115 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

No tests executed!

Other deprecation notices (1)

  1x: Since symfony/dotenv 5.1: Passing a boolean to the constructor of "Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv" is deprecated, use "Dotenv::usePutenv()".
    1x in Dotenv::__construct from Symfony\Component\Dotenv
```

Anyone has an idea no how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you "docker-compose up" is fired, you probably get the following warnings as well:

```
kalou@shinwey:~/t$ docker-compose  up
WARNING: The VULC_TARGET variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The VULC_PUBLISHED variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_TARGET variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_PUBLISHED variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MERC_TARGET variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MERC_PUBLISHED variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:

services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.mercure.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.vulcain.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

These 6 variables must be set before the "docker-compose up" command.

Comment: no that's the weird part, on `docker-compose up` I got no warning on that, meaning it manage to find them

Comment: Please add the option '--log-level WARNING' to your docker-compose call

Comment: I tested as such `docker-compose -f --log-level WARNING jcup/docker-compose.yml up -d;` or `docker-compose -f jcup/docker-compose.yml up -d --log-level WARNING;` but the version of `docker-compose` I'm using don't know this option. I'm using 3.4

Answer (score 0):

please try to down your containers with the corresponding --env-file like

```
docker-compose --env-file .config/.env.prod down
```